# Site is not working after implementing SSL IIS 8

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, asp.net

I have implement SSL certificate using steps given shown in below videos

[First Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGsm7mrfC0Q)

[Second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7USHit5mhY)

Once the changes are completed and  i tried to run the application, it shows "Site can't be reach".

Did i missed anything?
And another thing wanted to confirm, do we need to set entry in DNS for https as well?
We have set up DNS for without hhtps i.e. for http

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no way that anyone can help you based only on the information in your question. You will need to include actual configuration information.

Answer (score 0):

First or all DNS has nothing to do with protocol in use.

In my experience it could be the bindings.

Can you post a picture of your IIS bindings?

How to: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx